# Footer div on the left and on the right

Tags: html, css

I want like this:

```
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|left                           right|
|                                    |
```

It's on the footer and one is left,the other is on the right.
My code failed to do it. How to solve it?

```
 <div style="height:15%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;width=100%">
   <div style="float:left;left:0;width:100px;border:1px solid red">footer leftest</div>

   <div style="float:right;right:0;width:100px;border:1px solid green;">footer rightest </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gclsoft/xdUdE/

Comment: width=100% is correctly width:100% http://jsfiddle.net/xdUdE/2/

Comment: it's not `width=`, it's `width:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo: width=100% should be `width:100%`

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/xdUdE/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align if you want to align inline elements like text or pictures:

```
<div style="height:15%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;">
   <div style="float:left;text-align:left;width:100px;border:1px solid red">left</div>   
   <div style="float:left;text-align:right;width:100px;border:1px solid green;">right</div>
</div>
```